# How can I autofill to last row of data using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I select two columns and add a formula in them. Then I wish to autofill to the last row. However, every week the same dataset gets additional rows and I do not know how to autofill it so that it goes to the last row. Currently I have it so that it autofills to the 5000th row but however that creates anomalies. How can I make it so that the formula I have gets autofilled to the last row?

```
Range("BG1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total_Time_Spent (Dev)"
Range("BG2").Select
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-47]=R[-1]C[-47],SUMIF(C[-47], RC[-47], C[-20]), SUMIF(C[-47], RC[-47], C[-20]))"
Range("BG2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BG2:BG5000")
Range("BG2:BG2108").Select
Range("BH2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-48]=R[-1]C[-48],SUMIF(C[-48], RC[-48], C[-20]),SUMIF(C[-48], RC[-48], C[-20]))"
Range("BH2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BH2:BH5000")
Range("BH2:BH2108").Select
Range("BH1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total_Time_Spent (UAT)"
```

Comment: Which of the questions in this site that deal with Autofill using VBA have you looked at? Because that question certainly has been asked before. Did you even try to search? Please learn [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Easier to write the formula to the whole range in one go

```
Sub Demo
    Dim lr as Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lr  = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' adjust to a column that can identify the last data row

        .Range("BG2:BG" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=IF(RC[-47]=R[-1]C[-47],SUMIF(C[-47], RC[-47], C[-20]), SUMIF(C[-47], RC[-47], C[-20]))"

        ' etc

    End With
End Sub
```